# Does it really matter SWFObject instead regular embed?

Tags: flash, embed, swfobject

I see, it becomes popular to use SWFObject tag however does it really matter use swfObject scripts instead of regular embed tags ?
What is the difference, why they rather to use swfobject scripts?
I come up here while seeking the answer why sometimes my swf content does not load in the browser altough there is no problem at all.
I have tried swfobject (not within the head tag but in the body at all) but bingo same "sometimes not loading" problem appeared again.
It might be maybe because of my hosting service or hosting setting problem.
But if i am going to use swfObject and if i have to change website codes to make 100s of swf files work via swfobject then i have to understand well, why?

I read many documents but i can not see what is the difference than regular embed tags.

Btw. Market is turning to browser confilict competition, too many browsers, too many screen size, too many versions bla bla bla, and all over  that engineers are adding more complex alternatives over old tags. 10 years ago , even 15 years ago internet was more solid, fast,... sad!

Answer (score 2):

As detailed on the project homepage, SWFObject is no longer maintained and might not work in newer browsers.

`<embed>` is now officially a standard (part of HTML5), which means the page's HTML will now pass validation if you use `<embed>` instead of `<object>`. However, `<embed>` does not provide a way to display fallback content if Flash Player is not supported.

So the short answer is: if you don't want to use SWFObject, go old-school and use [the "twice cooked" method](https://alistapart.com/article/flashembedcagematch#section13).

```
<object width="300" height="120">
   <param name="movie" value="myContent.swf" />
   <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="myContent.swf" width="300" height="120" />

   <p>If you're reading this, your browser does not support Flash SWFs</p>

</object>
```

Comment: So if one fails other will replace in this case? So can we triple cook it with also the  swfobject? I will keep on my eye, if i will crash with non-appearing swf files again